# how to append HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name in response ASP.NET_SessionId

Tags: c#, asp.net

In order to prevent Session Hijacking I need to append HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name in response ASP.NET_SessionId, I am using IHttpModule for encrypting response cookie (Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300500.aspx).

HttpContext.Current.User is null.

Pls suggest where I am doing wrong.

global.asax
`

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
{
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
{
FormsIdentity id =(FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;
string userData = ticket.UserData;
string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);

string str = Request.Cookies["ASP.Net_SessionId"].Value;
}
}
}
```

Comment: What are you using for security, Forms auth? Has the user authenticated when you check the value

Comment: I am using Form auth. checking user auth in  global.asax file (Application_AuthenticateRequest)

Comment: Add the code from global.asax where your doing this, will help ans the question

Comment: can somebody help me on this?

Comment: if your worried about session hijacking you should be using SSL

Comment: thanks @prospector, SSL is ok, but what i am asking is possible or not?? if not then why?

Comment: @VishwanathMishra it's not a good solution, only use ssl